# el Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un problema en esta parte:

```vb
Private Sub mostrar()
    Try
        Dim func As New fClientevb
        dt = func.mostrar
        Datalistado.Columns.Item("Eliminar").Visible = False
dv.RowFilter = Cbocampo.Text & "like'" & Txtbuscar.Text & ""
```

Me marca como

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Corrige la indentación en la última línea en caso de ser necesario.